# Convert an HTML list of elements into columns

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code (a wrapper and a list of elements)

```
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
  1. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled.</div>
  <div class="item">
  2. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
  <div class="item">
  3. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Dhen an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled.</div>
  <div class="item">
  4. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled.</div>
  <div class="item">
  5. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Dhen an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled.</div>
  <div class="item">
  6. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Dhen an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled.</div>
</div>
```

and I'd like to get this using CSS:

[image]

The real challenge is that this has to be solved only using CSS since I'm using AMP and I don't have access to JS.

So far I am here:

[image]

```css
.items {
  margin: 0 -10px
}

.items:after {
  display: table;
  content: ''
}

.items .item {
  width: calc(50% - 42px);
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    1. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled.</div>
  <div class="item">
    2. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
  <div class="item">
    3. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Dhen an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled.</div>
  <div class="item">
    4. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled.</div>
  <div class="item">
    5. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Dhen an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled.</div>
  <div class="item">
    6. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Dhen an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The question has been well and truly answered, I think, but my only question remains: why not use an `<ol>` element, then the numbering would be automatic (though that's perhaps why you *didn't* use an `<ol>` of course), such as: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3wdavp4o/

Comment: Definitely the "grid" seems like the proper answer. Yes, the <ol> would be easier, I think I went for <div>s to make it more general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set it as a two column grid.

Obviously you'll want to set the gap and the padding to suit your usage.

```css
.items {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 3vw;
}

.item {
  border: solid blue 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    1. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled.</div>
  <div class="item">
    2. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
  <div class="item">
    3. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Dhen an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled.</div>
  <div class="item">
    4. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled.</div>
  <div class="item">
    5. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Dhen an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled.</div>
  <div class="item">
    6. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Dhen an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
.items {
    margin: 0 -10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: baseline;
}
```

```css
.items {
  margin: 0 -10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.items:after {
  display: table;
  content: ''
}

.items .item {
  width: calc(50% - 42px);
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    1. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled.</div>
  <div class="item">
    2. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
  <div class="item">
    3. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Dhen an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled.</div>
  <div class="item">
    4. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled.</div>
  <div class="item">
    5. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Dhen an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled.</div>
  <div class="item">
    6. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Dhen an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled.</div>
</div>
```